# How to skip unnecessary sequence in text with flex/bison?

Tags: bison, flex-lexer

I have a large text document, with some plain text and class definitions in it. What I want is to separate class definitions from plain text using flex/bison.

I tried next tip:

```
test.l
...
"class" :  { return CLASS;} 
"aligned": { return ALIGNED;} 
"extends": { return EXTENDS;} 
...
.* {return UNKNOWN;}

test.y
DocText : plainText
 | classDefinitions 
 | plainText classDefinitions DocText
 { printf (" parsed iso doc!\n" );};

plainText: UNKNOWN | UNKNOWN plainText;
```

This doesn't work. Could anyone please give me some advice about how I can fix this problem.

PS: sorry for my English.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!  Just to let you know, the "flex" tag refers to Adobe Flex; for your question, the "flex-lexer" tag is better.

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't use colons in your flex patterns (unless you want to match a colon). The pattern

   ```
   "class":
   ```

   will only match

   ```
   class:
   ```
2. Flex always chooses the longest possible match. It only prefers earlier rules if more than one rule matches the longest possible match. So if you have

   ```
   class { return CLASS; }
   .*    { return LINE; }
   ```

   and the input is

   ```
   class something
   ```

   Flex will match the entire line as LINE. The `class` rule will only be selected for a line which only contains the word `class` (without whitespace).

So you need to be a bit more precise in your token recognition. In general, even for simple applications, you need to correctly handle (almost) all tokens, including string literals and comments. (In this case, you could let many keywords be matched as identifiers, since you only care about a few keywords, but that is only a small simplification.)